# C - creating a packet using char and int

Tags: c, char, int, append, packet

I'm looking to build a binary string that consists of hex values... I've learned sprintf is not the correct way to accomplish this. I've got a real simple gui to collect configuration settings that need to be sent a device. The values can be signed and will always be numerical. I have a set of values like:

```
#define PKTHEAD 0xA5
#define VALONE  0xA0
#define VALTWO  0xA1
#define VALTHREE 0xA2
#define PKTTAIL 0x5A

signed int val1 = 10000; //0x2710
signed int val2 = -84;   //0xFFAC
signed int val3 = -175001 //0xFFFD5467
```

My end goal is to have a packet that would resemble "PKTHEAD|PKTHEAD|PKTHEAD|VALONE|val1|VALTWO|val2|VALTHREE|val3|PKTTAIL|PKTTAIL|PKTTAIL", and the hex representation would be A5A5A5A000002710A1FFFFFFACA2FFFD54675A5A5A.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numBytes = 10;
    signed char *tmp;
    signed char *pyld;
    pyld = calloc(numBytes, sizeof(char));

    signed int val1 = 10000; //0x2710
    signed int val2 = -84;   //0xFFAC
    signed int val3 = -175001 //0xFFFD5467

    tmp = pyld;

    *(tmp + (numBytes - 1)) = DACHEAD;
    *(tmp + (numBytes - 2)) = DACHEAD;
    *(tmp + (numBytes - 3)) = DACHEAD;
    *(tmp + (numBytes - 4)) = VALONE;
    *(tmp + (numBytes - 5)) = val1;
    printf("payload = %hhx%hhx%hhx%hhx%hx%hx%hhx%hx\n", pyld[9], pyld[8], pyld[7], pyld[6], pyld[5], pyld[4], pyld[3], pyld[2], pyld[1], pyld[0]);
}
```

The output is: "payload = a5a5a5a0100a1ffac"

My val1 value is incorrect and I'm wondering if there is a better way to compose this packet. Should I be doing bit shifts instead?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way of sending data over network is using a serialization library. For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168863/looking-for-c-serialization-library)

Also, if you do not want to use external libraries you should first understand `integer` sizes that you need, either it is `16 bit` or `32 bit`, the `endianness` (and convert accordingly) that your device uses and always prefer using `memcpy` for putting values of correct size into binary buffer.