# system call to populate struct values

Tags: c, pointers, struct, system-calls

I'm trying to populate `struct` values using system calls. My initial effort follows. However i get junk values from the print statement.

```
int fd;
int nbytes;
struct message {
  char *from;
  char *to;
  int size;
};
struct message m1={"me","you",10};
struct message m2;

fd=creat("structfile",0644);
nbytes=write(fd,&m1,sizeof(m1));
read(fd,&m2,nbytes);

printf("%s %s %d",m2.from,m2.to,m2.size);
```

Is there another way to do this? (I'm thinking of the way that structures like `hostent` and `dirent` are filled up directly by making calls to `gethostbyname` and `readdir` respectively)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:**

Where is `fd` intialized?

**Problem 2:**

The line

```
nbytes=write(fd,&m1,sizeof(m1));
```

write the numerical values of the pointers `m1.from` and `m1.to`. It does not write the strings they point to.

If you want to write the contents of `m1`, you have to serialize the contents of `m1.from` and `m1.to`. There are libraries for that purpose. You can see some references from [How to serialize data in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168863/looking-for-c-serialization-library).

Comment: Sorry. Corrected fd initialization.

Comment: @user3818219, In addition to the problem of using `write` for an object of type `struct message`, you also have the problem that `fd` oints to the end of the file after the write. There is nothing for `read` to read.

Comment: @RSahu fd doesn't really point anywhere; that could be confusing language to someone new to C. it is basically a constant integer that references the `open`ed file ... you have to use `lseek` (or similar) to tell the kernel to move around the *unbuffered* file (file descriptor as opposed to FILE*)  ... one of the easiest ways to transmit strings is a size:values method such as 5hello5world or <integer>"string" `write(fd,strlen(s),sizeof(size_t));write(fd,s,strlen(s));` and then on the other end `read(fd,len,sizeof(size_t));read(fd,string,len);...` Note: integers are endian dependent

Comment: @technosaurus: the *other* easy way to transmit strings is using fixed-length strings - [`dirent`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991334/members-of-dirent-structure) does. This removes the need for allocating and freeing memory for each string.

Answer (score 1):

`Problem 3`, your struct contains character pointers:

```
struct message {
  char *from;
  char *to;
  int size;
};
```

Your `sizeof(m1)` writes the size of `2 (char *) pointers` and `an (int)`. The data pointed to by `from` and `to` can vary based on the size of the string. Reading `sizeof(m1)` does not take into account the size of the strings pointed to.